# Android Studio does not download the SDK. same zip file repeated in details

Tags: android, download, sdk, components

I installed from

```
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/3.0.1.0/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows.exe
```

All seemed well until setup tries to download Components.
Expanding the detail shows these lines repeated infinitely.

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
```

I can download the file fine in a browser no problem.
My guess is a permissions error for the temp directory where it is try to download it. But I see no errors and don't know where that is. And that is only a guess.

I downloaded https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.1.0/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows.zip
and extracted it to C:\devel\android studio. Ran studio64.exe and had the same problem.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: I downloaded prerelease Android Studio 3.1 Canary 7 https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.1.0.6/android-studio-ide-173.4524538-windows.zip

Comment: Extracted it and ran studio64.exe. It did not get stuck on downloading the zip. It did seem to hang at the end of the installing components. There were no reported errors though. I killed it and started up again and everything looks to be ok. On to trying to develop my first app. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download The file with any download manager
2. Extract the downloaded zip file.
3. Copy the folder named m2repository from the extracted folder.
4. Navigate to extras/android directory in your SDK installation
   directory. For me it's:
   C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\

   Replace the existing m2repository folder with the one from the ZIP.
   (It's better if you create a backup first)
5. Restart Android studio.

   **ATTENTION:**  Seeing these lines in details is not infinite and does not necessarily mean that installation stuck! be patient check your net usage and you'll see that Android Studio is trying to download the file! But if you really can't stand not seeing the progress you can manually download the file and extract it as I told you earlier.

Comment: I did let it go for a long time, like 30 min. At that time I also did try download it manually like you describe but it just moved on to the next file it wanted to download and did the same thing, repeating the url of the file it was trying to download. I did it for a few more files manually hoping to get over a "hump" but to no avail.

Comment: I'm no longer working on the project and uninstalled the whole thing since I don't need it. And it appears 3.1 fixed the problem (described in comments to original post). So to me, the only point this post serves is for anyone having problems installing Studio 3.0 to just install 3.1. Or be happy with manually downloading, unpacking and renaming MANY sub packages. Unless the 3.0 branch is going to be maintained and others are able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: like I said printing the same line over and over does not mean that it's stuck and the download time depends on your network connectivity. I had the same issue and seen many had it but in low speed networks if you manually 2 or 3 files the rest will be downloaded soon

Comment: and also bare that in mind dear @cando that in some countries because of sanctions you will not be able to download these packages without a proxy I don't suggest that and don't know the legal implication of that but the technical answer is that you have to use a proxy!

Comment: Interesting point Ali M. But non of which was the case here. I'm in USA and had excellent connection speed. I was able to download the zip file manually in a minute or two without setting up any proxy. And that was also done in the middle of the time it was "trying" to download the package automatically which I gave like 30 min before I canceled. I also tried it multiple times.

Comment: Oh! I'm running out of answers here but hope that you'll find yours. please share your findings with us